# Можно ли поключить платежи через Payeer в телеграм боте? Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, платежи

Хочу переписать оплату платежей с QiwiApi на Payeer, но не нашел примера оплаты на нем
Вот исходник без ответа: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445563/Можно-ли-подключить-payeer-к-своему-телеграм-боту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445563/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-payeer-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83)